# What is this use of 様 in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage

The sentence is

> ああ、この女の様は溺れているようだ。

I'm assuming it is さま and not よう in this case, but why is it there?

Comment: https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E6%A7%98_%28%E3%81%95%E3%81%BE%29/ Definition 2

Comment: Or [this](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%A7%98-1), if you are more comfortable reading Japanese English dictionary entries.

Comment: I see. I had never seen it in the form of nounの様 before. Thanks both of you.